# Lightbox is not closing in some browser apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am using lightbox in my page. While closing light box it is closing fine in all browser.. But it is not properly closing in Opera..

My light box component code -

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="ShowFlag" type="Boolean" description="Boolean with a get/set property) passed from the page to the lightbox controller" ></apex:attribute>
    <apex:attribute name="Close" type="ApexPages.Action" description="The action from the main controller to put the lightbox flag back to false"></apex:attribute>

    <apex:form >
      <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="black-overlay" rendered="{!showflag}" id="lightboxbackground"/>
      <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="lightbox-container" rendered="{!showflag}" id="lightbox">
        <div style="text-align: right;">

            <span class="action-button-x" style="margin: 2px;">

                <apex:outputlink>X</apex:outputlink>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="lightbox-content">          
            <apex:componentbody />   
        </div>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>

</apex:component>
```

When i clicked in close button in other browser it is closing..
I checked in console for error but no error is present..

Please Guide me !!